aiogram 3 handlers
перехожу с 2-ой версии на 3-ю, надо перенести фабрику хэнддеров, как это можно сделать в новой версии?
dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'], state='*')

во второй версии было так.

Теперь в 3 версии вам надо заменить dp.register_message_handler на dp.message.register. Остальное не меняем. Источник
